# URL is support in Desktop but not in salesforce mobile app

Tags: url, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

/lightning/o/Task/new?defaultfieldvalues=whatId='+objectId+',ActivityDate='+string.valueof(Date.today())+'&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FOpportunity%2'+ObjectId+'%2Fview'

by using this URL I get related values also.But this URL is not supported on mobile

I removed **defaultfieldvalues** from URL its working fine in Both Desktop and mobile but not got related  values ...

/lightning/o/Task/new?whatId='+objectId+',ActivityDate='+string.valueof(Date.today())+'&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FOpportunity%2'+ObjectId+'%2Fview'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaQKC.png)

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.links_useful_custom_buttons_create_record_dfv.htm&type=5

> This feature applies to Lightning Experience in all editions. This
> feature **doesn’t apply to** Lightning Out, Experience Builder sites, or
> **the Salesforce mobile app**.

In mobile app see if you can achieve something cool with a quick action (they can have default values too). Otherwise it's developer time and whip up custom aura/lightning web component.